# How can you calculate the specific fan power of a fictitious HVAC system?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power

I am working on a concept involving an HVAC system drawing air in from outside.

Known information: Air flow rate (calculated), change in pressure accross fan (given) and total efficiency (assumed). No other information is available and would have to be assumed or neglected.

P_el = Air flow rate * change in pressure

I worked out that with an air flow rate of **5000 l/h** and delta p of **100 Pa**, I would have a P_el of 0.139W. With an efficiency of **60%**, that's 0.232 W.

My system operates for **1600 h/a**. How do you report the result? I.e. do I have to multiply the 0.232W by 1600 h? Is the result actually correct? My professor gave me the pressure drop value of 100 Pa, which seems very low to me.

This is definitely not my area of expertise. Many thanks in advance!